# How to create folder actions on OS X that run when the folder is "opened"

Tags: macos, filesystems, file-management

I want to create a folder action that is run every time a folder is opened, instead of only when files are added to the folder. From what I've found online, there doesn't seem to be a way; is there or are there any alternatives to accomplish this? I'm running OSX Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do once the folder is opened? Maybe there is a better solution than an action on just the folder opening.